# How we resolve Check self permission error Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

"checkSelfPermission" showing me an error I try to read many content on stack still i am not able to resolve this

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this ,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{

}
```

-

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.googlemap"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Above line also showing me an error 
 [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade all the dependencies to their Android counterparts.

Secondly, don't use `compile` -  use `implementation` instead.

Change

```
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

to

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

And similarly, upgrade all dependencies to the latest Android libraries.

Comment: still showing red signal ,can you show for this line what dependencies require may be this work for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211259/discussion-between-android-id-and-jai-mahesh).

Comment: Here my build.grade file  https://ideone.com/rQXKHL        Please take out me from this error

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is a dependency-type conflict. You are using an androidx and an old support type of the same library. Here are two quick fixes to help you:

- Change all your dependencies to Android. To do this, you can left-click on the dependency and selecting *migrate to AndroidX*. Also, remove duplicate dependencies; there is no need for the support app-compat dependency.
- Change `compile` to `implementation` in your Gradle file. Also change `testCompile` to `testImplementation`.

I hope this helps.